# Can we run wpf application with other credentials other than logged in person?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, batch-file

Can we run a wpf application .exe file with some other credentials other than the one whose has logged into that system, with out prompting for new user credentials.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a batch file containing the `RUNAS` command in the following manner:

Example: Run notepad.exe as the user Jdoe on domain SS64dom with no profile:

```
C:\> Runas /noprofile /user:SS64Dom\jDoe "notepad.exe"
```

You will have to enter the password when prompted.

In addition you can install the free CPAU tool from joeware.net:

[joeware.net](http://www.joeware.net/freetools/) - CPAU (Create Process As User) like RunAs but with an options to encrypt the password and no need to set password when prompted.

Direct link to the tool download and guide: http://www.joeware.net/freetools/tools/cpau/index.htm

Source: http://ss64.com/nt/runas.html